# showing UnityEngine.Sprite after text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code right now: `using System.Collections;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class easyModeImageSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int rand;
    private int newRand;
    private int randForButton;
    public List<Sprite> image_pic2 = new List<Sprite>();
    public List<Sprite> image_pic3 = new List<Sprite>();

    int previousresult;

    public List<TMP_Text> optionBUttonText = new List<TMP_Text>();
    private void Start()
    { 
        rand = Random.Range(0, image_pic2.Count);
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = image_pic2[rand];
        //image_pic2.RemoveAt(rand);
        RandomizeText();
    }

    public void NextRound()
    {
        rand = Random.Range(0, image_pic2.Count);
     
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = image_pic2[rand];
    }

    public void RandomizeText()
    {
     
        newRand = Random.Range(0, image_pic3.Count);
        randForButton = Random.Range(0, optionBUttonText.Count);
        optionBUttonText[randForButton].text = image_pic2[rand].ToString(); // over here it also 
        shows 
        UnityEngine.Sprite
        image_pic3.RemoveAt(rand);
    
        optionBUttonText.RemoveAt(randForButton);
        int i = 0;
        while (i != 3)
        {
            Debug.Log("running other button");
            newRand = Random.Range(0, image_pic3.Count);
            randForButton = Random.Range(0, optionBUttonText.Count);
            if (newRand == previousresult)
            {
               Randomize();
            }
            optionBUttonText[randForButton].text = image_pic3[newRand].ToString(); // over here it 
            also 
            shows UnityEngine.Sprite
            optionBUttonText.RemoveAt(randForButton);
        
            previousresult = newRand;
            i++;
        }
    }

    void Randomize()
    {
        newRand = Random.Range(0, image_pic3.Count);
        randForButton = Random.Range(0, optionBUttonText.Count);
    }
   }`
```

And here is the result for this code:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhdOA.png)

The problem is that when you play the game the text on the buttons show the name, but then also add 'Unityengine.sprite' on it afterwards and I am researching but I am not sure how to fix this issue.

I think that you have to add something in the brackets of the ToString() but im not sure what.

If anyone knows how to fix this could you please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get the name of the `Sprite` GameObject that you see in the Hierarchy, use `.name` instead `.ToString()` method. Using `.ToString()` method will result in getting not just the name of the GameObject but also the data type.

In your case, instead of `image_pic2[rand].ToString()`, use `image_pic2[rand].name`.